# pytest fixture that gets data from a database - limit to one call?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a fixture that queries a MongoDB database and returns a record.

```
@pytest.fixture
def chicago():
   return GetRecord("CHICAGO,IL")
```

Each time I pass this fixture into a test, it runs the query again. Is there a best practice on how to make it so I only run this DB call once? I found I can do something like this, but it seems to defeat the purpose of a fixture.

```
chi = GetRecord("CHICAGO,IL")

@pytest.fixture
def chicago():
    return chi
```

I could just pass in `chi` instead of declaring a fixture if this is the alternative. Any other solutions?

Comment: You could use a session-scoped fixture (`@pytest.fixture(scope="session")`).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen this seems to kind of work but also seems slower than declaring the variable outside of the fixture block. Does setting up a session scope take more overhead?

Comment: Are you sure? In comparison with the database query any overhead here should not matter - not that I'm aware of any. Did you measure the time? Oh, and there is a difference of course: in the first case (global var) the query is made on loading the test, in the second (session scoped fixture) on calling the first test, so that may change the measured time, depending on how you measure it.

Comment: May have been background work or something else with my laptop, I just tried a few more times and I'm seeing the expected performance now. If you'd like to submit your solution as an answer so I can accept it, that would be great. I wasn't able to find the scope setting in my Google searches so this could gain some traction over time.

Answer (score 1):

To have a fixture only evaluated in a certain scope, you can set the fixture scope. As described in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session), there are five scopes that affect the context in which a fixture works. Basically a fixture is setup at the begin of the scope, and cleaned up at the end of a scope.

If you need the fixture to be initialized only once over all tests in a session, like in your case, you can use session scope:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def chicago():
   return GetRecord("CHICAGO,IL")
```

This will be evaluated once, as used by the first test, and would be cleaned up, if there were any cleanup code, after all test executions have finished.

Here is a simple example to show this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def the_answer():
    print("Calculating...")
    yield 6 * 7
    print("Answered the question!")

def test_session1(the_answer):
    print(the_answer)

def test_session2(the_answer):
    print(the_answer)

def test_session3(the_answer):
    print(the_answer)
```

This results in:

```
$ python -m pytest -s session_based.py
==================== test session starts ====================
...
collected 3 items

session_based.py Calculating...
42
.42
.42
.Answered the question!

==================== 3 passed in 0.32s ====================
```

As you can see, the "calculation" is done only once before the first test, and the "cleanup" is done after all tests have finished.

Respectively, the rarely used package-scoped fixtures are executed once in a test package, module-scoped tests are executed once in a test module and cleaned up after the tests in that module finish, class-scoped tests are executed once per test class, and function-scoped fixtures (the default) have the lifetime of a single test that uses them.

I'm quite sure that has been answered before, but as I could not find a matching answer, here you are.